# check if a connection to an Active Directory server is secured (encrypted)

Tags: active-directory

**Context**

For a number of actions (for example: in order to accept to execute a "password change" or a "password reset" query), an Active Directory requires that the connection between the client and the server is secure.

"secure" connections include for example :

- connections established through LDAPS
- plain + StartTLS connections
- SSPI encrypted connection

We have code for an LDAP client, which uses a sub library to establish a connection. Depending on the parameters used when creating the connection, it may either be a plain connection, or a "secure" connection, using one of the medium listed above.

We want to run password modify/password requests on that connection, but before running the actual query, we would like to check whether the connection is secured.

We have access to the code of the sub library, so we can modify the code of that library to have a boolean which indicates whether we went through one of the encrypted paths, I would however like to know whether there is a way, using an LDAP query, to determine whether the current connection is deemed "secure".

**Question**

Is there a way to check, through a request to the AD server, whether the current connection is considered "secure" from the server's point of view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no query you can make to determine whether the connection is encrypted.

Depending on the library you're using, it may be able to tell you after the fact if the encryption is encrypted, but usually you would specify it up front, so you can just keep track of whether you did it.